# rails 4 attr_accessor and new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Booking with attr_acessor :date and time:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  before_save :convert_date_and_time

  attr_accessor :date, :time

  def convert_date_and_time
    self.date_and_time = DateTime.parse("#{date.to_s} #{time.to_s}")
  end
end
```

I am trying to define getter methods for date and time:

```
  def date
    date_and_time.to_date if self.id.present?
  end

  def time
    date_and_time.to_time if self.id.present?
  end
```

but I think this is not quite the way to do it. I need self.id.present? because when I am trying to create a new record, obviously date_and_time still has no value and the getters will yield errors.

If that is the case, how should the getters look like so that I can handle new records that are not yet saved? Should I leave them like how they are now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To detect new record you can use [`new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F), but in your case you can use [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) :

```
date_and_time.try(:to_date)
date_and_time.try(:to_time)
```